# auto resize mobile background image

Tags: image, mobile, autoresize

I couldn't find the exact answer for my problem, so thanks in advance.

I need to make a very,very mobile landing page, which include only an image (320X480px) and a button. I managed to insert the image and the button, yet I cant find the right way to make it auto-fit the screen (iphone 5, iphone 4 etc.).

I don't need it present a different image for every platform, just resize it automatically when needed.

I guess I should use CSS but I'm a beginner, so be gentle with me :)

example page: http://canbonim.co.il/test/test.html

code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=iso-8859-8-i">
    <title>XXX</title>
</head>
<body> 
    <div style="position:relative; width:320px; height:480px; margin:auto; background:url(http://www.canbonim.co.il/test/test.jpg) top left no-repeat;">
        <div style="position:absolute; top:0px; right:0px; width:320px; height:480px;">
        <a class="link" title="" style="position:absolute;top:343px; left:38px; width:249px; height:48px;" href="tel:035142212"></a> <!-- -->
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

can you please try below code. You will get the output but it is not the good way to go with. Use Responsive design like bootstrap n all.

```
<div style="position:relative; width: 100%; height:480px; margin:auto; background:url(http://www.canbonim.co.il/test/test.jpg) top left no-repeat;background-size: 100% 480px;">
        <div style="position:absolute; top:0px; right:0px; width: 100%; height:480px;">
        <a class="link" title="" style="position:absolute;top:343px; left:38px; width:249px; height:48px;" href="tel:035142212"></a> <!-- -->
        </div>
    </div>
```